# Should I separate "message" into 2 tables?

Tags: sql, database-design, chat

Let's say we have a chat system where a user can send a message either:

- to a channel
- to a specific user

I have to choices:

1. Either one table for message that has `channel_id` and `recipient_id` as foreign keys. The problem with this is that the table will most likely be much bigger than the the tables in the 2nd point + it will have a lot of null values (since all private messages have `channel_id` null and all channel messages have `recipient_Id` null).
2. 2 separate tables: one for private messages and one for channel messages. This avoids bloating 1 table with null values, but we end up having 2 very similar tables to maintain (since they must have almost the same attributes).

I am not a database expert and it would be nice to get some insights about the 2 points. Which one to go with and why?

Comment: There's no absolute answer but the table being bigger is not necessarily an issue. For this kind of app, it might actually make more sense to use a schemaless database like CosmosDB or Firebase

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Could you give me details?

- How is the table being bigger not an issue? Doesn't that make queries slower?
- What makes a schemaless database better?

Comment: Why not have a single recipient table that contains a flag whether the recipient is a user or a channel? Then the messages table would only need a single foreign key

Comment: A common mistake when designing is thinking that table size is an issue when often proper index design sorts it out or there are rarely any reads, or the data size is actually not that large. If you have a lot of data to be stored that consists of messages and those messages are very different, schemaless can be better. It's worth considering sometimes when issues come up about "how do I design it.. all my fields are going to be empty". There is plenty of info online about schemaless / NoSQL if you want to research further

Comment: With regards to all the NULLs, at the physical level you can define that as a sparse column and it may save space. You can use filtered indexes to make queries run faster. There's a lot you can do. From a modelling perspective, have a think about in future, will channels and private messages become very different? If you can see in future that these two things might get new features that make them even more different then that would indicate that you should put them in two different tables. Or maybe in future there will be something else different to a channel or private message

Comment: How would indexing help here? Can you index on nullable values such as channel_id?

Answer (score 0):

If your priority is performance then go for the second option else, if you are concerned about size then, go for the first.

Alternatively, you can go with another approach :
Create one table as a history table and set the flag as false for column "new record" and dump all the data which is sent already to the history table and new data(yet to be send) in the main table with flag "New Record"=true.
this way you can maintain your first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Create a channel for each pair of communicating users. Then there will be no distinction between messages to channels and messages to users.

I find it convenient to name peer to peer channels as

`[prefix][lesser_user_id][separator][greater_user_id]`

For instance, a channel between users 56789 and 12345 could be named `chan12345.56789`. 
In such a case when you need to find the appropriate channel between two users all you need as their IDs.